# Replacing emojis with text in PHP

Tags: php, replace

My goal is to take all the emojis in a string and turn them into their text versions.

For example, the smiling emoji will become ":)"

I know I could use pre_replace, but i don't know where to start.

Comment: "I know I could use pre_replace, but i don't know where to start." With the documentation? http://php.net/preg_replace

Comment: No, more like what do emojis look like to php? what would i tell preg_replace to look for?

Comment: It looks like what you have there `:)`.. or if it looks differently only you could tell us that. You could use `str_replace` also if the values are static. `print_r`, `var_dump`, or `echo` could be used to see what your values are. Depending on where you are outputting you may need to encode it. It also is unclear what a `text version` of an `emoji` would be.

Comment: I would take a look at https://github.com/iamcal/php-emoji

Comment: @TheWebDev Try just `str_replace('', ':-)', $string)`... I'm able to type raw emojis into my PHP code just fine.